# When plotting the cosines of the phases of some sensors, I got an interesting plot

Tags: fft, phase, fourier

I have a laser that I modulate at some frequency, typically 1250 Hz. I have a sensor that tracks what happens inside a reactor when it's illuminated. I am doing Fourier analysis on both the laser modulation signal and the sensor, and extracting the components at 1250 Hz, forming a time series of phases.

I was playing around with these phase relationships in Excel and I came up with this plot. Laser is the x-axis, sensor is the y-axis. I'm trying to think back to college because I swear I've seen something like this before, but would appreciate any commentary!

[image: what is this even]

Comment: Well, by construction, it's a Lissajous curve made with 2 sinusoids of the same frequency, with a particular phase between them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve#Application_for_the_case_of_a_=_b .  The elliptical shape is a function of the phase delay whuch depends on the system and your method of measurement.

Comment: Lissajous curve! Thank you, that was the term I was trying to remember.